# Is this a correct expression for a primality test using the Dirac delta?

Tags: dirac-delta, primality-test

$$\int_{1/2}^{n+1/2} \delta(1 - \cos(2 \pi x) + |sin(n \pi / x)|) \,dx$$

The idea here is $1- cos(2 \pi x)$ is zero at the integers, positive otherwise, and $|sin(n \pi / x)|$ is zero at real factors of $n$, positive otherwise. Adding these two yields a function that's zero at integer factors of $n$, but positive otherwise. Filtering this through $\delta(x)$ and integrating from a half to $n+1/2$ should count the number of whole factors of $n$. And of course if this equals two than $n$ is prime.

**Update**

As per comments, this is just a bit of curiosity as I'm not actually sure it's valid. Can this be considered a "smooth" analogue of the above?

$$\int_{1/2}^{n+1/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} dx} \exp\left(-(1/dx)^2 \left(1 - \cos(2 \pi x) + \sqrt{sin(n \pi / x)^2+dx^2}\right)^2\right) \,dx$$

Comment: Possible that this test works , but it is of no practical use.

Comment: Yes, thank you, and might a hypothetical smooth analogue have some practical use?

Comment: I don't think this works. One potential problem is composition of Dirac delta with a function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function), but $g(x)=1-\cos(2 \pi x)+\left|\sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{x}\right)\right|$ is not even a smooth function.

Comment: Thanks, any thoughts on the update?

Comment: There are many limit representations of the Dirac delta function (e.g. see https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/). Why does $d$ appear three times in the integrand of your update? Was this just a typo and these should be deleted?

Comment: It's dx's inside the integral. I'm an amateur, just playing with ideas.